# js find xml attribute with another attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml

I have some XML as below. If I know the title attribute is: c4d5c5 how do I get the mode attribute (four)?

```
    <swatch title="af588b" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="one"></swatch>
    <swatch title="b1977c" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="two"></swatch>
    <swatch title="bfca64" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="three"></swatch>
    <swatch title="c4d5c5" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="four"></swatch>
    <swatch title="c5dbd9" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="five"></swatch>
    <swatch title="c181a4" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="six"></swatch>
    <swatch title="ca936c" name="color" width="50" height="50" mode="seven"></swatch>
```

Something like this? (this does not work but this is where I am at the moment)

```
    $(xmlDoc).find('swatch').each(function() {
        var myMode = $(xmlDoc).find('mode[title="c4d5c5"]');
        console.log(myMode+" myMode");
    });
```

Comment: is there a toot element for the xml

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the [attribute equals selector](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) with `swatch` and then use [.attr()](http://api.jquery.com/attr/) to read the attribute value like

```
var mode = $(xmlDoc).find('swatch[title="c4d5c5"]').attr('mode');
```

Comment: Thanks Arun thats great. Any way to stop the function once the mode is found?

Comment: you need to share the complete context of the problem

Comment: which function has to be stopped?

Comment: I thought it might be good to stop looking through the XML once the attribute has been found?
I have added the function to be stopped to the answer. Just say if you don't think it needs to be stopped. Thanks.

Comment: @user2238083 if you replace your code with the above one there is no need to stop

Comment: I don't need the each function? Sorry I thought I still needed the each function, I don't. Thanks Arun.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60359/discussion-between-arun-p-johny-and-user2238083).